# Can't figure out why Erlang function is undefined

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have a function that keeps giving me "function codes/3 undefined" error. Here is the code for the function:

```
table(Sample)->
Freq=freq(Sample),
Tree = huffman(lists:keysort(2, Freq)),
codes(Tree).

codes(Tree)->
    {_,_,X,_}=Tree, <---- Masks out a tuple
    {Y,_,_,_}=Tree, <----- Masks out an atom
    codes(X,Y,[]). <------ Here is where it gives error.

codes({},_,List)->List;
codes(Entry,Type,List)->
    case Type of
        leaf->
            NewList=[element(3,Entry)|List];
        node->
            Entry1=element(2,Entry),
            Entry2=element(2,Entry),
            codes(Entry1,element(1,Entry1),List),
            codes(Entry2,element(1,Entry2),List);
    end.
```

Can't figure out why, does anyone know?

*EDIT: the problem was a `;` after the final `end` rather than a `.`, now fixed.*

Comment: There is obviously one more error in this code: `syntax error before: 'end'`. Remove the last `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though someone else solved the question, below is the structure from the [erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html)

```
case Expr of
    Pattern1 [when GuardSeq1] ->
        Body1;
        ...;
    PatternN [when GuardSeqN] ->
        BodyN
end
```